# ZX Spectrum emulator?

Tags: emulator

Can you recommend a free/shareware/commercial [ZX Spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum) emulator (Windows or Linux)?

What are the gotchas for the one you are using/have been using?

I still have a lot of ZX Spectrum programs that I would like to resurrect.

Answer (score 2):

All the [emulators](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/emulators.html) available today, for different platforms.

Got some links for you: 
[Ergon's ZX Spectrum emulators WEB page](http://www.geocities.com/siliconvalley/park/6533/zxemulators.htm), 
[Speccy: Portable Sinclair ZX Spectrum Emulator](http://fms.komkon.org/Speccy/) and 
[Spectaculator, Sinclair ZX Spectrum Emulator Home](http://www.spectaculator.com/).

Comment: Which one have you used and what is your experience using it?

Answer (score 0):

I play a lot of the spectrum games in the past and from all the [ZX Spectrum Emulator](https://www.gamulator.com/emulators/zx-spectrum/windows) I always play the games with the Fuse.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience there are a total of 4 emulators you can go with, well, there may be more but compatible with probably less than 10% of the games. These are Retroarch, Fuse, ZX32 and ZX Spectrum 4. My personal best is the [ZX32 emulator](https://www.romspedia.com/emulators/programs/zx32) solely because it I have had most success in terms of ROM compatibility and also the controller configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Best since years:

http://torinak.com/qaop

Qaop - ZX Spectrum emulator.

There are menus appearing on the left and right if you double-click on the screen. Seems like the emulator is written in JavaScript.

Also there are games available immediately:

http://torinak.com/qaop/games

And other emulators:

http://torinak.com/qaop/links

The emulation is extremely well polished. You can also save locally programs, screenshots and load them again to the emulator.

Some years ago well known was Z80/WinZ80 which was best emulator for DOS and earlier Windows versions. It had many emulation options (like speed, ZX Spectrum version, some tweaks).

Also there is Java version of Qaop available to run emulator on different OSes (Windows, Linux, maybe Mac OS).